# Bind9 for Single Machine DNS Name Server and Host

Tags: debian, dns, bind9

I'm trying to set up Bind9 on a Debian 10 machine so that I can access it by using its domain name and am having difficulty in getting it to work. I'm sure I'm doing this wrong.

My IP Range is 192.168.20.1/192.168.20.150 and the Debian machine is on 192.168.20.87.

I've applied the following configs

`named.conf.options`

```
acl "trusted" {
        192.168.20.87;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { trusted; };
        listen-on { 192.168.20.87; };
        allow-transfer { none; };
        forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

`named.conf.lan`

```
zone "deb10serv.lan" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.deb10serv.lan";
        allow-transfer { none; };
};

zone "reverse.deb10serv.lan" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.reverse.deb10serv.lan";
        allow-transfer { none; };
};
```

`zones/db.deb10serv.lan`

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.deb10serv.lan. admin.deb10serv.lan. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; NS
@       IN      NS      ns1.deb10serv.lan.
@       IN      NS      ns2.deb10serv.lan.
; A
ns1.deb10serv.lan.    IN      A       192.168.20.87
ns2.deb10serv.lan.    IN      A       192.168.20.87
; HOST
host.deb10serv.lan.   IN      A       192.168.20.87
```

`zones/db.reverse.deb10serv.lan`

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     deb10serv.lan. admin.deb10serv.lan. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; NS
@       IN      NS      ns1.deb10serv.lan.
@       IN      NS      ns2.deb10serv.lan.
; PTR
87.20   IN      PTR     host.deb10serv.lan.
```

Bind9 seems to start up ok without any issues but I am unable to ping ns1.deb10serv.lan, ns2.deb10serv.lan or host.deb10serv.lan. An nslookup on 192.168.20.87 is also failing. I'm certain I've done something wrong

*UPDATE*

I just realized that the Bind9 port was being blocked by the firewall, adding it (53 upd) sorted it out

Comment: Perhaps just for the time being, I would suggest changing the `allow-transfer` lines to match the `allow-recursion` line.  Being able to request zone transfers can be a helpful debugging tool.

Comment: Additionally, there are several diagnostic utilities provided with BIND.  `named-checkconf`,  `named-checkzone` and friends may be of help.  For starters, your `zone "reverse.deb10serv.lan"` should be `zone "168.192.in-addr.arpa"`  Lastly, unless and until you get things working, use much smaller `TTL` values, so that wrong RRs aren't cached for excessive periods of time.  Once it works and your RRs are stable, then you can increase the `TTL` values.

Comment: I just realized that I'm an idiot and it was being blocked, I had to make a rule for port 53udp for it to work

Comment: also, you don't need to specify the full domain name of a resource record inside the zone file.  it defaults to the current domain name, aka `$ORIGIN` or `@`.   e.g. `ns1 IN A 192.168.20.87` is the same as `ns1.deb10serv.lan. IN A 192.168.20.87`.   In fact, the trailing `.` after the `.lan` is there to prevent the zone file's $ORIGIN from being appended.

Comment: @JimL. the zonefile's filename can be anything at all, as long as $ORIGIN is set correctly in the file.  See, for example, [DNS $ORIGIN dot](https://serverfault.com/questions/879913/dns-origin-dot)

Comment: @cas That's not the filename, that's the DNS zone that the zonefile applies to (default origin).  An `ORIGIN` line *can* be used in the zonefile, but is not necessary if the `zone` parameter in the `named.conf` is sufficient.  The filename is the `file` line, and indeed, that can be anything you want.  My comment refers to the `zone` line, which generally needs to specify the DNS zone being served.

Comment: @JimL. you're right. i thought you were talking about the filename only.  didn't notice that the actual zone definition was wrong.

Comment: @cas, I was naming every excessively explicitly for the purpose of debugging but is it better to use the shorter domain name in the A records?

Comment: @JimL., does the name of the reverse zone file need to be named in that way? I'm unaware of what the standard for reverse zones is or what the name `168.192.in-addr.arpa` actually means

Comment: @TheLovelySausage well, it's a lot less typing.  so a lot less chances to make a typo.  (btw, the single most common typo with zone files is either forgetting to add a trailing `.` when you've typed the full DN, or accidentally deleting one - and ending up with hostname.example.com.example.com or worse instead of just hostname.example.com)

Comment: @cas, that makes sense

Comment: You might find [this reading](https://www.apnic.net/about-apnic/corporate-documents/documents/resource-guidelines/reverse-zones/) helpful.